# ubuntu 20.04 でアプリケーションランチャアイコンの実行許可設定

Tags: ubuntu

ubuntu 20.04 で、次のようなファイルを作成しました。

**/home/username/デスクトップ/myapp.desktop**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=MyApplication
Exec=/usr/local/bin/myapp
```

このファイルに対して実行権限を付与しました。

`chmod +x myapp.desktop`

以前のubuntuでは、こうしてできたアイコンをダブルクリックすると、アプリケーションが起動できたと思いますが、ubuntu 19 以降では、さらに、アイコンを右クリックして、メニューから「Allow Launching」を行わないといけないということでした。

以上の方法で、実行可能なランチャアイコンをデスクトップに作成する方法は分かったのですが、この「Allow Launching」というのは、内部的に何を行っているのでしょうか？

ユーザーの操作で Allow Launching を行うのではなく、スクリプトやプログラムで Allow Launching と同等の設定を行う方法はあるでしょうか？